# Multiple gitlab accounts with different users but same SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

We use gitlab online for work and I have a work gitlab sign in account to get access to it. I have setup my PC to use git config global settings for my user.name and user.email. I have a generated public SSH key in ~/.SSH/id_rsa.pub and added it to my work gitlab account. Everything works like a charm.

I also have a private personal gitlab account with differing details. My repository when cloned from gitlab for my personal project on my PC has overridden user.name and user.email in the .git/config file. However I want to be able to use a new SSH key associated with this account without wiping my work one? How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or a custom installation? And your personal and work account are they both on gitlab.com or the custom installation?

Comment: Both on gitlab.com online

Comment: My advice is use only 1 account that makes things a lot easier than it is now. You could ask your company to use your personal account instead of having 2 accounts. Or add both ssh keys to your work account and personal account. You can even add multiple e-mail addresses to 1 account that should also help you out. I think you user.name is always the same since your name does not change. Your e-mail can be different but you can add multiple e-mails to your account so that should not be a problem.